# Javascript, returning value from a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 functions in javascript:

```
function A(){
     B(data);
}

function B(data){
    element.on('click',function(){
         C(data);
    });
}

function C(data){
    //Process data
}
```

Function C does all data processing, but the data needs to be passed only on the click event, which I have defined in B. So, I need to pass data to B too, to ensure that C gets it. Here, A is my main program and I'd rather not define the click event there. Is there any other way to pass data directly to C from A?

Comment: So basically, you call A() which then calls B(). Then you wait for the click, and on click you execute C()?

Comment: What is wrong with the solution you have now?

Comment: Yup. I'm really new to Javascript and Im not sure if this is a proper way of doing stuff.

Comment: @putvande: The data differs each time A is called. But B does a lot of stuff, like creating div elements using d3. If I call it again, an entirely new set of elements are created. If I dont call it again, C gets the same old data over and over again, which is also not desirable. There are various workaround, but, just wanted to know if there were any methods in JS to simplify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any other way to pass data directly to C from A?

You will need to pass the *call of C with th data* to B for that:

```
function A(){
    B(function(){
         C(data);
    });
}

function B(data){
    element.on('click', callback);
}

function C(data){
    //Process data
}
```

It would work the same way as the code you already have, but has decoupled B from C.

Comment: So, if C has a return value, where would this value get returned to? A or B?

Comment: Neither. Callbacks don't `return` anything, they *pass* their results on (also called continuation-passing-style). You might use `C()`s (synchronous) results  in the anonymous function though